# Accessing factories in the same Angular module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, removeall, cachefactory

In my Angular app, I have some resource modules, each containing some `cache` factories.

For example,

```
projectRsrc.factory('getProjectCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory){
    return $cacheFactory('getProjectCache');
}]);
```

I have a few of these to cache values received from the servers.

The problem is that at times I'd like to clear all the caches. So I want to put all the `cacheFactories` into one `CacheCentralApp` module and delete all the caches with a single call.

The trouble is, I don't know of any way to access other factories inside my module. So for instance, if I create a module `CacheCentralApp`, and in it, declare factories that provide `cacheFactory`s, how can I create a function in there that calls `removeAll()` on every `cacheFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to target all the factories of a certain module. I think however that another solution to your problem is to send a event that all factories has to be cleared. This will prevent that you will have to loop through all your factories and call a .clear() function on everyone.

You could send a event request with the following code:

```
$scope.$broadcast('clearAllCaches');
```

And listen to this event in every factory with:

```
$scope.$on('clearAllCaches', function() {
    clearCache();
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea... but are you sure that `$scope` works inside factories?

Comment: Inside the factories, you will have to inject $rootScope and subscribe with `$rootScope.$on`

Answer (score 0):

In a separate module you might create a factory for that:

```
var cacheModule = angular.module('CacheCentralApp', []);
cacheModule.factory('MyCacheFactory', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
  var cacheKeys = [];
  return {
    clearAll: function() {
      angular.forEach(cacheKeys, function(key) {
        $cacheFactory.get(key).removeAll();
      });
    },
    get: function(key) {
      if(cacheKeys.indexOf(key) == -1) {
        cacheKeys.push(key);
        return $cacheFactory(key);
      } else {
        return $cacheFactory.get(key);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

To create new or get existing `Cache` you simply call `MyCacheFactory.get(cacheName)`. To clear all the caches ever created in the factory you call `MyCacheFactory.clearAll()`.

*Note:* I am not quite sure that `Array.indexOf` is available in every browser, you might want to use `Lo-Dash` or another library to make sure your code works.